# Relate stock location to product model - OpenERP report

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I made a new report on OpenERP, for stock module, which uses the `product.product` model, like the default one which is `Stock Level Forecast`.

Now, what is the problem I have, I need this report to be shown on "Location Structure->Physical Locations->Warehouse->Analyze current inventory"

It is showing there, no errors, everything's fine, but my problem is, because this report is tied to `product.product` I need to show some product fields (already declared on report) and the `location_id` of the warehouse I'm querying.

Obviously if I loop over the current location on my report, it throws an error, because this is a `stock` object, and not from product.

So, my question is, how can I bring all product fields into stock, to effectively report all product fields AND stock location at the same time?

I guess I should make a related field, or a one2many there, but I'm very confused at this point.

Any ideas?

I hope I explained myself, if you need the code please let me know I'll edit my question then.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @NeoVe, I'm trying to do same kind of report and wonder if you could share your code about what you did ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi renard, I'm using zestybeanz printscreen module, that saved my life hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a parser for you report. And it is this parser that returns the list of products.

Comment: Yes, it has it's parser, a basic one, no need to relate fields or inherit classes? If yes, I'll modify it.

Comment: I need the location_id also, which is from stock module, should I declare this on the parser too?

Comment: On your parser, you do what you want. And after you can call the parser methods in the report.

Comment: Oh, awesome! I'll try it